# Compare values from multiple hashes within an array

Tags: ruby, arrays, for-loop, hash

I know for-loops should be avoided and i guess the better way to iterate through an array is instead of doing

```
for i in 0..array.size-1 do
  puts array[i]
end
```

do

```
array.each{ |x| 
  puts x
}
```

But what if i had an array of hashes like

```
array = [{:value0 => 1, :value1 => 0}, {:value0 => 2, :value1 => 1}, {:value0 => 1, :value1 => 2}]
```

and wanted to check if :value0 is unique in all hashes.. intuitively I would do something like

```
for i in 0..array.size-1 do
  _value_buffer = array[i][:value0]
  for j in i+1..array.size-1 do
    if _value_buffer == array[j][:value0]
      puts "whatever"
    end
  end
end
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Oh, and, btw, you *never* need to use `for` in Ruby. if you really need the index you can use [`each_with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) or [`with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index), or possibly `(0..(array.size - 1)).times { |i| ... }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just get all the values in question and see if they’re unique?

```
!array.map { |h| h[:value0] }.uniq!
```

([`uniq!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq-21) returns `nil` when there are no duplicates)

Comment: Do you want size equal to 1? Or the length of the array? That is a good solution.

Comment: @squiguy You’re right, but I’ll bypass that entirely to keep the solution a variable and tap-less one-liner `:)`.

Comment: That's pretty clever, I never really think to use the destructive methods. +1

Comment: @andrew marshall Ah, ok I was a bit confused due to your answer before editing but this is rrrreally neat- Thanks!

Comment: @squiguy I usually avoid destructive methods, but I think it’s okay here since it’s on a just-functionally-created array that’s just going to be thrown away anyway.

Answer (score 2):

As what Andrew Marshall says, you can use uniq!, but with a more concise way:

```
!array.uniq!{|a| a[:value0]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it:

```
2.0.0p195 :001 > array = [{:value0 => 1, :value2 => 0}, {:value0 => 2, :value2 => 1}, {:value0 => 1, :value2 => 2}]
 => [{:value0=>1, :value2=>0}, {:value0=>2, :value2=>1}, {:value0=>1, :value2=>2}] 
2.0.0p195 :002 > val0 = array.map { |hash| hash[:value0] }
 => [1, 2, 1] 
2.0.0p195 :003 > puts val0.uniq == val0
false
 => nil
```

I would collect the values of `:value0` and then compare them to the array of unique values.